# How to solve error -36 on enqueueWriteBuffer?

Tags: c++, opencl

I have this code that I followed from a tutorial. I've used vcpkg with Visual Studio 2019 to setup opencl.

```
#include <CL/opencl.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
    if (all_platforms.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cl::Platform default_platform = all_platforms[0];
    std::cout << "Using platform: " << default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << "\n";
    std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
    default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
    if (all_devices.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "No devices found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cl::Device default_device = all_devices[0];
    std::cout << "Using device: " << default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << "\n";

    cl::Context context(default_device);

    cl::Buffer buffer_A(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * 10);
    cl::Buffer buffer_B(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * 10);
    cl::Buffer buffer_C(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(int) * 10);

    int A[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int B[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0 };

    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);
    auto err = queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * 10, A);
    if (err != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "error on writting to buffer_A, err=" << err << std::endl;
        return err;
    }
```

It crashes on `enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int)*10, A)`. It seems that everything initialized correctly. I'd like to know if anyone had this issue using the OpenCL C++ api. Thanks.

Graphic card: GTX1060
OS : Windows10

Answer (score 0):

Error code -36 is „invalid command queue“, so you should check the error code of the CommandQueue creation. The constructor of CommandQueue can take an additional `cl_int *err` parameter for this.

Comment: cl_int error;
cl::CommandQueue queue(context, 0, &error);